# `click()` in click event handler

Tags: javascript

Test:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button')
btn.addEventListener('click', log)

function log(event) {
  var p = document.createElement('p')
  p.textContent = event.type
  document.body.appendChild(p)
  fire()
}

function fire() {
  btn.click()
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

I think an exception will be thrown. `click()` in click event handler dispatches a click event, the click event handler calls `click()` again, which again dispatches a click event, and so on. But the result is not the same as I thought , it only outputs two 'click'(IE outputs one 'click').

Now change the `fire` function, create a click event and dispatch it, the result is as expected.

```js
  var btn = document.querySelector('button')
  btn.addEventListener('click', log)

  function log(event) {
    var p = document.createElement('p')
    p.textContent = event.type
    document.body.appendChild(p)
    fire()
  }

  function fire() {
    var event = new MouseEvent('click')
    btn.dispatchEvent(event)
  }
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

My question is why `click()` behaves differently?

**Notice**: jQuery is not used, there is nothing to do with jQuery method `.click()`.

Answer (score 1):

`dispatchEvent` sends the event synchronously to the target, so when you use `dispatchEvent` the event handler frames accumulate on the stack and eventually overflow. therefore, printing infinite `click`and filling your stack (console exception). see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

However, when you use .click() a controlled event in javascript. it simulates only one event i.e. `click` instead of the continuous sync calls. see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) for more help.

Comment: Well, jQuery is not used here.

Comment: appologies. but both the methods(`click()` of `JavaScript` and `JQuery) work in same manner. see the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your `.click()` does action associated with it (like following link) bud does not triggers `click` event > no `log` function called again, so no repetitive click event executed.

In second version you constantly triggering `click` event, so your `log` function is executed infinite times.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Why is log not called again?

Comment: @Rajesh No `click` event executed - no `log` function executed

Comment: @Justinas why are `log` and `fire` called twice? According to you, `log` should've been called just once. But console.log shows two executions: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/82d39L4n/1/